# OpenCV build issue, can't find ext/atomicity.h

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

I get the compiler error complaining about `<ext/atomicity.h>` when building a project incorporating OpenCV.  Environment is Xcode 4.5 targeting iOS.  It compiles fine for the simulator but fails when building for the device.  Here's the error text:

```
/Users/Nick/projects/ios/opencv2.framework/Headers/core/operations.hpp:65:16: fatal error: 'ext/atomicity.h' file not found
      #include <ext/atomicity.h>
```

I'm using the opencv2.framework, builusing cmake, using the instructions [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default XCode 4.5 generates new projects to build using the `libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++ 11 support)`.  But OpenCV is expecting to be built against the GNU `libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)`.  `<ext/atomicity.h>` is apparently a GNU extension and isn't part of the LLVM libc++ standard library.

In your project's target settings, select `libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)` for the C++ Standard Library setting.

Very likely the atomicity.h requirement could be factored out of opencv or otherwise done in a LLVM libc++ compatible way.  I didn't explore this but would be interested if anyone had insight on how this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the other way around. Looking at the output of the python script that builds opencv2.framework I get this:

> --     C++ flags (Release):         -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC   -DNDEBUG -O3 [...]

which is most likely not what you want. So you need to compile the framework with libstdc++ or compile your app with the proper lib. From what I see I get problems when building my apps with libc++ but that might be me.