# What is libc++ and libstdc++

Tags: c++, libstdc++, libc++

I have a couple of questions.

1) What is `libc++` and `libstdc++` ?

2) What is the difference between them ?

3) Are they interchangeable ?

4) Is it something a compiler should implement ?

5) When should I use one or another ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972425/should-i-use-libc-or-libstdc?rq=1

Answer (score 13):

libstdc++ is the GNU c++ standard library implementation.

libc++ is the LLVM/clang c++ standard library implementation.

Even when compiling with clang, libstdc++ (gnu) is often used (on Linux).

A main reason libc++ (clang) exists is that libstdc++ (gnu) is GPL and so Apple can't ship it, so you can think of libc++ as the non-GPL libstdc++.

Answer (score 10):

> 1) What is libc++ and libstdc++ ?

They are implementations of the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header).

> 2) What is the difference between them ?

They are entirely different implementations.

> 3) Are they interchangeable ?

Yes, you should be able to use them interchangeably. (However you can't easily use both in the same program.)

> 5) When should I use one or another ?

You shouldn't have to worry about that. Your code should work with *any* standard library implementation.

Comment: While point 5 is theoretically true, I've encountered several instances where one is buggy so you have to use the other.  For instance, regex's with libc on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Saying entire different in this case, for differences doesn't help a bit :)