# gcc .map lists both libstdc++.so and libcpp.so - which one will be used for string, vector, etc

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, map-files

My `.map` file for the `gcc` linker output contains both `libstdc++.so` and `libcpp.so` and I've read that [they're incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972425/should-i-use-libc-or-libstdc)

How will it know which C++ `lib` to select?
If this executable instantiates a `string` then passes it to another executable that also has both `libstdc++` and `libcpp` in .map file . . . will things work out?

Documentation is appreciated.

Comment: Your link refers to `libstdc++` and `libc++`. But `libc++` is not `libcpp`. The first is the the LLVM Standard C++ Library.
The second is the proprietary Dinkumware Standard C++ Library,
which has been licensed to various proprietary toolchains. Nobody here is more likely than *you* to know why you are linking these two implementations of the Standard C++ Library, and as whether they are ABI compatible, you'd best ask [Dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com/) or the toolchain provider.

Comment: @MikeKinghan thank you I will. Is there a list of all these `std` lib implementations and their incompatibilities?

Comment: No. Linking multiple implementations of "the same" library should not be done unless with expert rationale and scrutiny. If you don't know why you're
doing it, you should assume its wrong until you can find out.