# Fatal error: 'ext/atomicity.h' file not found using OpenCV 2.4.11

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I found that maybe the problem is with standard library... But I don't know how to change it using Cmake.
I tried many options but is not working.

My **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/cpp', 'src/main/jniLib/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary2411')
}
```

and my **CMAkeList.txt** looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

#set(ANDROID_STL "c++_shared")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# OpenCV IMPORT
include_directories(C:/OpenCV-android-sdk_2_4_11/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library( lib-opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib-opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java.so)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp
             main.cpp
             )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

I checked [this link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support) but is for ndk-build... But I'm working with cmake (Android Studio 3+)

Answer (score 0):

You right the problem is because the stl [libc++]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037661/5052296

To change the STL in your **build.gradle**:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared'
        }
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake

---

*Another option:*

To edit the "include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp" file.

Comment: Thanks! arguments '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared' worked well. Now I'm having this other at linking time: error: undefined reference to 'cv::solve(